# Jersey 2.26 - NoSuchFieldError when starting server

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to setup a simple server using Jersey and Jetty. However the code from [Jersey documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.http) throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: GIT_HASH
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(JettyHttpContainerFactory.java:305)
at org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(JettyHttpContainerFactory.java:135)
at com.zoho.dfs.App.main(App.java:17)
```

Here's my `App.java` class:

```
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://127.0.0.1/").port(8050).build();
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(RestController.class);
        Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, config);

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and `RestController.class` (I want to map an

```
@Path("/{username}")
public class RestController {

    @GET
    @Path("/home")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response read(@PathParam("username") String username) {
        String name = "hello " + username;

        return Response.status(200).entity(name).build();
    }
}
```

and here's the `pom.xml` dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried with adding dependencies like `jersey-server`, `jersey-container-servlet-core` etc also. It's the same error. What could be mistake I'm doing?

Comment: `jersey-container-jetty-http` already pulls in Jetty. Maybe version incompatibility. Try removing the Jetty deps.  If you want servlet support use the `jersey-container-jetty-servlet` instead and use `JettyWebContainerFactory`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `jetty-server` and `jetty-servlet` from your dependencies , they will be pulled in by `jersey-container-jetty-http` and `jersey-container-jetty-servlet`, which you need to add. Here's some basic dependencies you'd need to integrate `jetty` and `jersey`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also, in your `App.java`, you do not need to do `server.start()`.

```
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://127.0.0.1/").port(8050).build();
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(RestController.class);
        Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, config);

    }
}
```

When you  do `JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, config)`, it creates a container with the given `config` and then creates a server and starts it.